# how to index a json file with nested array with solr

Tags: json, solr

I've got a json file which contains nested arrays like [[0.5, 0.25, 0.75], [0.5, 0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5, 0.5]],but when I tried to index the json file, it got flatten result like [0.5, 0.25, 0.75,0.5, 0.5, 0.5,0.5, 0.5, 0.5]. Can anyone tell me how to deal with that?

Comment: When you say index, do you mean you want to search by that field or just to save the data? If it is the latter, could you just serialize it as BLOB?

Comment: What do you want to *find*? Because there is no point indexing something if you can't use it to find things. Or do you just want to store it and not search over it at all?

Comment: these data are a list of coordinates of atom(the number of this list is not certain), because it might be useful in certain condition(like search by number of list or the complete array complete with some condition etc.),so I tried to save and index it.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest the arrays in objects, like this:

```
coords: {
{[0.5, 0.25, 0.75]}, 
{[0.5, 0.5, 0.5]}, 
{[0.5, 0.5, 0.5]}
}
```

**coords** must be a multi-valued field.